# PHP Imagick Extension instead of Command/Exec

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, dreamhost

Having used PHP GD for some time I have decided to move to Imagemagick. The way of running it on the host is as follows:

```
$command = "/usr/local/bin/convert $commands";
exec($command);
```

Is there any way to be able to switch the implementation so that I can use the php Imagick extension (which seems more logical for me to code for)?

The site is hosted with Dreamhost.

Comment: Have you considered using phpThumb? At least it should provide you with a unified inteface, while it can utilize both php-gd and imagemagick

Comment: It is a great library indeed, and highly capable- however it may be too much for some simple requirements, and not be a fit for others- I also want to understand whether/how it would be possible to load IM as an extension vs exec command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have lots of php with Imagemagick examples on my website and have started on some Imagick examples.

As you know you can run Imagemagick through exec() which is the way I do it as I think it is simpler and has access to all the Imagemagick operators included in your version.

There is Imagick built into php 5 which is slightly quicker than exec( ) but you will see from other posts it is not very well documented and quite hard to learn.

I write my code like this which has the benifit of echoing the $cmd and checking it is what you wanted when using variables in the code.

```
$cmd = " $input -resize 500x500 $output ";
exec(" convert $cmd ");
```

Comment: I guess I have to concede that this seems like the best approach, many thanks